# The cardinality of the maximal linearly independent susbet of a free module over a commutative ring with the identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, cardinals, free-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with the identity and $F$ be a  free-module over $R$.

I assume $X$ is the basis of $F$.I know any two bases of $F$ have the same cardinality.

My question is that can we get that the cardinality of the maximal linearly independent susbet of F is less than the cardinality of $X$, ie if $Y$ is any maximal linearly independent susbet of F,can we get $|Y|\le |X|$.

If $|X| $ is finite, it is true. How about $|X|$ is infinite?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30066/cardinality-of-maximal-linearly-independent-subset?rq=1) MO question, if $A$ is a commutative ring with unit and $M$ is a free $A$-module of infinite rank, then all maximal linearly independent subsets of $M$ have the same cardinality. Apparently this can be found in a paper by Lazarus, _Les familles libres maximales d'un module ont-elles le meme cardinal?, Pub. Sem. Math. Rennes 4 (1973), 1-12_.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor  Thanks!